# Java throwing class cast exception even if types are correct

Tags: java, spring-boot, foreach, collections, classcastexception

I was learning about Matrix Variables in spring boot but I encountered problems while extracting the data.

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/{query}/plan", produces = {"application/xml"})
   public ResponseEntity<List<PlanDTO>> fetchPlansByLocalRate(@MatrixVariable(pathVar = "query") Map<String, List<Integer>> map){
       
       Set<String> keysLocalRates = map.keySet();
       Set<Integer> localRates = new HashSet<Integer>();
       
       keysLocalRates.forEach(key -> {
           map.get(key).forEach(val -> localRates.add(val)); // throwing exception here
       });
       
       return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(planService.fetchPlansByLocalRate(localRates));
       
   }
```

It is throwing following error

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (java.lang.String and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
> at com.infy.controller.PlanController.lambda$0(PlanController.java:51) ~[classes/:na]
> at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeySet.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:589) ~[na:na]
> at com.infy.controller.PlanController.fetchPlansByLocalRate(PlanController.java:50) ~[classes/:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
> at

I can't understand where am I going wrong.

Edit:

I still can't understand this strange behaviour as I have already declared List as `List<Integer>` but it is having `List<Object>` so I tried following code and it works fine

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/{query}/plan", produces = {"application/xml"})
    public ResponseEntity<List<PlanDTO>> fetchPlansByLocalRate(@MatrixVariable(pathVar = "query") Map<String, List<Integer>> map){
        
        Set<String> keysLocalRates = map.keySet();
        Set<Integer> localRates = new HashSet<Integer>();
        
        keysLocalRates.forEach(key -> {
               map.get(key).forEach((Object val) -> localRates.add(Integer.parseInt((String)val)));
           });      
        
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(planService.fetchPlansByLocalRate(localRates));
    }
```

Comment: are you sure the map is mapping to `List<Integer>`? Based on the error message, it looks like there is actually a `String` inside an `ArrayList` (despite the type of the `map` parameter)

Comment: I get the same Exception at exactly the same location - line 1511 from `ArrayList` - when doing `( (List<Integer>) new ArrayList(List.of("test")) ).forEach(System.out::println)`

Comment: You are using raw types and creating an `ArrayList<String>` and trying to cast it to a `List<Integer>`. `"test"` is not an `Integer`.

Comment: @David that is intentional - to show that the problem is having a `String` inside a `List<Integer>` ("*I get the same Exception at exactly the same location ...*")

Comment: @user16320675 I'm sorry, I mistook you for the OP. I should read more carefully.

Comment: @user16320675 I tried to extract the value in `String` but it is giving compilation error which means it is not `String`  inside `ArrayList`  `keysLocalRates.forEach(key -> { String x = map.get(key).get(0); System.out.println(x);});`

Comment: @user16320675 I even tried to get what type is inside `ArrayList` using `getClass()` like this `map.get(key).get(0).getClass();`  but even this is giving me classCastException

Comment: if the list contains a `String` instead of the declared `Integer`, the `get(0)` method will throw that Exception (before you can assign it or call `getClass()`)

Comment: @user16320675 I still don't understand how can be there string in `ArrayList` if I have already declared it `List<Integer>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253543/discussion-between-sandeep-shiven-and-user16320675).

Comment: For debugging I'd suggest breaking it down into `for()` loops and intermediate variables to get a better sense of exactly what step the error is occurring in, and lets you add print/log statements (or use a debugger if that's available). You can put it back together then.